# Прописывание пути в PATH

Tags: python

Я установил Python 2.7 на Windows 7, прописал путь к нему в PATH. Дальше хочу выполнить мою программу, например example.py, выполняю python example.py получаю ошибку, так как python не найден. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вы уверены, что не найден именно python,а не example.py? Попробуйте полный путь до example.py или, для начала, киньте его в корень python27

Comment: @moron перенес в корень, все работает, указал полный путь до example.py получаю ошибку, причем именно unknown command:python

Comment: покажите Ваш PATH

Comment: @vinger4 C:\Python27\python.exe

Comment: была ли перезагрузка или "перечитывание" PATH?

Comment: @aapetrov3 если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста проголосуйте за полезный с вашей точки зрения, и примите лучший, тот, который вам действительно помог. Очень важно голосовать за ответы и принимать их, не забывайте об этом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте таким образом:

```
c:\Python27\python.exe example.py
```

или так:

```
C:\AllProject.Python>c:\Python27\python.exe example.py
```

Переходите в директорию к примеру *C:\AllProject.Python>*, далее находясь в этой директории выполняете команду **c:\Python27\python.exe example.py**

Comment: второй вариант работает в командной строке, но, например в Git уже не работает, выдает permission denied

Comment: в Git попробуйте так:
sh python example.py